# R packages (e.g. lubridate) not working when called with Rscript as cron job

Tags: r, cron, lubridate

Let's say I want to have my computer calculate my age every minute, therefore I run the following cron job everyday:

```
*/1 * * * * bash /path/to/birthCalc
```

birthCalc itself calls an R script, like so:

```
#!/bin/bash 
Rscript birthCalc.R
```

Now, this all works, if I use base R with such a birthCalc.R:

```
birthDay <- as.POSIXct ('1919-04-15', format = '%Y-%m-%d')
age <- floor ((as.numeric (Sys.time ()) - as.numeric (birthDay))/(365.25*60*60*24))
```

However, if I try to use the following script using lubridate library, it does not work anymore.

```
library ('lubridate')
birthDay <- as.POSIXct ('1919-04-15', format = '%Y-%m-%d')
age <- floor (lubridate::time_length (Sys.time () - birthDay, "years"))
```

If I run `installed.packages ()` inside the cron job, lubridate is listed, so I assume the cron job should be able to find the library. I have had this problem with other libraries, as well, but choose lubridate as an example.

The script only fails when run as a cron job. I can run it fine from a bash terminal or interactively in R. I checked that cron uses the same Rscript and R, as well as that the packages are accessible. What am I missing?

I am running:

R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)

Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit) with Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS

lubridate_1.7.4

Many thanks,
TTR

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. It seems to have been related to permissions. I created the cron job as root originally and tried to create it for a user. Using `crontab -u user -e`, instead of `sudo crontab -e` solved the issue. Does somebody know why this was an issue, despite the libraries being installed in accessible directories?